# Optimal way to load dynamic JavaScript bundles

Tags: javascript, webpack, lazy-loading, dynamic-loading, dynamic-import

When loading JavaScript-code dynamically, there are at least two possible approaches.

One approach is to load the code as a string with [`XHR`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)/[`Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and then to execute it with [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)/[`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Another approach, which is actually used by [Webpack dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), is to insert a `<script>` element to the document and wrap the bundle's code into a JSONP callback function. This way, the code will be loaded and compiled by the browser automatically, and the wrapper function will be called to notify that loaded code is ready to be executed.

Yet another approach is implemented in [dynamic-import-polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/dynamic-import-polyfill) by GoogleChromeLabs. They are creating a script element and passing dynamically generated code to load the requested file using blob src:

```
const moduleBlob = new Blob([
  `import * as m from '${absURL}';`,
  `${importFunctionName}.moduleMap['${absURL}']=m;`,
], {type: 'text/javascript'});
```

But, it requires a basic support of some ESM features (not available in legacy browsers like IE 11) and requires [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to be properly configured when present.

The `eval` / `Function` approach looks more convenient, because it's simpler  and allows to load module in any generic format, like CommonJS/AMD and it doesn't require a proprietary wrapper-function to be present.

What are the principal differences between these approaches? Which, approach is better? And why Webpack and Google decided to not use `eval`/`Function` approach?